# Flutter Firebase Auth / Google Sign in runtime type errors

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

[UPDATED]: Split the code into 2 functions as suggested by @Ashton to make things a bit simpler.
I am a noob with flutter and I am trying to do some really simple things with flutter i.e. building a login page with either firebase login or google login. I face errors with both and I am not able to find out what the reason is for it.

I have firebase setup and my GoogleServices-Info.plist file setup for ios development. The function doing the authentication for me as below.

```
Future<Null> _googleSignIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (user == null)
    user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  return user;
}
```

If I use the Google Sign in then I get the following error.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Null>' where
  _Future is from dart:async
  Future is from dart:async
  Null is from dart:core

#0      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall.<anonymous closure> (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:196:28)
#2      _RootZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1376:54)
#3      _FutureListener.handleWhenComplete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:151:18)
#4      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:603:39)
#5      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:659:37)
#6      _Future._addListener.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:342:9)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

However, if I call the firebase simple auth system, then if the user doesn't exist and I try to use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword then the following error comes back.

```
Future<Null> _firebaseAuthSignIn(String email, String password) async {
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
  try {
    firebaseUser = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    final userid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  } catch (exception) {
    firebaseUser = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
  }

  return firebaseUser;
}
```

Although, this creates the user in firebase, the function createUserWithEmailAndPassword causes the exception below..

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' where
  _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
  Map is from dart:core
  String is from dart:core

#0      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _ensureLoggedIn (package:remy/auth/login.dart:28:41)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      LoginPageState._handleSubmit (package:remy/auth/login.dart:64:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:remy/auth/login.dart:132:41)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:478:14)
#5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:530:30)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
#8      TapG<…>
```

My initial reaction was that since these errors look like type inconsistencies, the package versions were not latest. However, I double checked and my versions are upto date..

google_sign_in: 3.0.0
  firebase_auth: 0.5.1

Any help in the right direction would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: do yo have imports in `lib/main.dart` that don't start with `import 'package:..`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nopes. I have all imports starting with 'package'.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this also.

I think this might be a bug in version `3.0`. I downgraded to `2.1.2`

e.g.

`pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # ...
  google_sign_in: 2.1.2
```

And the issue disappear

Answer (score 1):

**for the error:**

type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

**Quick fix:**

In Android studio,

Settings -> flutter -> Run application in Dart 2.0 mode "Disable dart 2"

I am not sure why dart 2 causes this error; hoping someone can help understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

In this case, you don't have a return statement in the `use_google == true` block.

Try `return user;` which is of type [Future](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/lib/google_sign_in.dart#L237-L240)

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

I'm not exactly sure here. Perhaps it's the format of the input, how it's handled in the exception, or maybe the setup of firebase_auth in general. I recommend you split up the two different sign-in methods so you can return the appropriate type from each method, and so you can narrow your focus and see if that helps you uncover the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ashton. So I split up the function and added the return statement to the google Sign In.. The error is still the same. As for the firebase auth one, the setup is standard. `final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();` . Although for the firebase auth, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` causes the problem and throws the exception, I still see the user being created in firebase.

Comment: @ssarangi, so did you return the object in the google sign-in case? Did this remove the first issue? As for the second issue, can you start providing more code, context, logging so we can see if we can narrow our focus or uncover new information?

Comment: I did return the object in the google sign-in case and it didn't solve the first issue. For the 2nd issue, let me try to debug the api to see where this type mismatch happens. thanks for helping me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change the return type from:

```
Future<Null> _googleSignIn() async
```

to

```
Future<GoogleSignInAccount> _googleSignIn() async
```

Comment: That didn't fix the issue. Could be a problem with the version as mentioned above.